# how can I stop (or break) script with mouse move

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using some script  for my Indesign document. But i want to stop script when mouse cursor not move. When script run mouse moving in text (its normal). When the text it finish doesn't move any more, but script still working for loop finish. 
can i stop it when cursor not move.
Here is sample of my script

```
  Loop 100
{
Send ^{Numpad3}
Send ^{Down}
Send ^{Numpad2}
Send ^{Down}
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Please elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This stops the loop if the mouse is moved

```
MouseGetPos, x1,y1 
Loop 100
{

  MouseGetPos, X2, Y2

  if (X1 <> x2) or (y1 <> y2)
    break


  Send ^{Numpad3}
  Send ^{Down}
  Send ^{Numpad2}
  Send ^{Down}
}
```